# Linear formula calculation

Tags: math, formula

Recently trying to solve a problem which involves a formula.

I have one already as an example.

So

```
MIN 0.58 equals X = 0.50
MAX 1.23 equals X = 4.50
```

You can achieve any in between values with the following formula: (0.1621 * X) + 0.4990, works great.

Example:

(0.1621 * 1.20) + 0.4990 = 0.69, so 0.69 equals X = 1.20

However the scenario changed, and so the formula, and I can't find out.

```
MIN 0.59 equals X = 0.20
MAX 1.10 equals X = 4.80
```

Comment: `works great` Except `(0.1621 * 0.50) + 0.4990 = 0.58005` *not* `0.58`.

Comment: Forgot to add that +/- 0.01 is an acceptable margin of error considering the input value (0.50 in your example) most likely will be 0.501273 or something around that, as it is analog input.

Comment: The line through points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` is `y = y1 + (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) (x - x1)`. For the first case `(0,50, 0.58)` and `(0.58, 1.23)` this gives `y = 0.58 + 0.65/4 (x - 0.5) = 0.1625 x + 0.49875`. The second case calculates the same way.

Comment: I see that 0.1625 * 0.50 + 0.49875 equals exactly 0.58. Alright, but in your example to calculate the formula you didn’t use the 4,50 value? What I’m trying to achieve in the new formula is something around x* 0.20 + y = 0.59 and x * 4.80 + y = 1.10, both x and y being the same formula.

Comment: That was a typo, the second point was meant to be `(4.50, 1.23)` instead.

Comment: So pretty much the formula will be (0.11086957 * x) + 0.56784, am I close? x being 0.20 returns 0.59 and x being 4.80 returns 1.10!

Comment: That sounds about right.